# search form not working and gives error in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search

Im trying to implement a search field to an rails app I'm building to learn rails.

When I make a search rails throw back this error.

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ProductsController#search`

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "short_description" does not exist LINE 1: ...WHERE (name LIKE '%%' or description LIKE '%%' or short_desc... ^ : SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (name LIKE '%%' or description LIKE '%%' or short_description LIKE '%%')`

In my _navbar.html.erb I have this code

```
 <%= form_tag search_products_path, class: 'navbar-form navbar-right' do %>
   <%= search_field_tag class: 'form-control', :id => 'searchbar',  :placeholder =>'Search', :name => "query" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: 'btn btn-default', :name => nil %>
 <% end %>
```

and in the products_controller.rb I have this code

```
  def search
    @q = "%#{params[:query]}%"
    @products = Product.where("name LIKE ? or description LIKE ? or short_description LIKE ?", @q, @q, @q)
    @categories = Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:id => @products.map{|x| x.id }}).distinct
  end
```

And in the routes.rb I have this line of code

```
post 'products/search' => 'products#search', as: 'search_products'
```

Can someone please help me with this, I´m not experienced enough to figure this out by my self.

Comment: Could you please provide a part of your schema.rb for `products` table? It seems  `short_description` column doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, thats so true :)  I deleted it from the code, it looks like this now and works very well `@products = Product.where("name LIKE ? or description LIKE ?", @q, @q)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the products controller you have this ActiveRecord code:

```
Product.where("name LIKE ? or description LIKE ? or short_description LIKE ?", @q, @q, @q)
```

In that SQL string you're referencing `short_description`, which is apparently not a column on the `products_table`.

You can generate a migration to add the column like so:

```
rails g migration AddShortDescriptionToProducts short_description:text
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I ended with just deleting it, I didn´t need this column.... now the line looks like this `    @products = Product.where("name LIKE ? or description LIKE ?", @q, @q)`and works like a charm. It was some leftovers in the line since earlier, my bad